# Crashlytics not being called?

Tags: android, android-fragments, crashlytics

Trying to call from static function? Its initialized because it calls from the onCreate of the activity. Wondering how crashlytics works.. does it require reference to some context that is somehow not present. Here is some code:

Calling from the activities menu override:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.explore:
            ListFragment.injectNewList(ListActivity.this, Stuff.getRandOffset());

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Calling function is a static function within a fragment:

```
public static void injectNewList(FragmentActivity activity, Integer offset)
{
    ListFragment fragment = (ListFragment) activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                                     .findFragmentByTag(BaseFragmentActivity.LIST_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    if(fragment != null)
    {
        fragment.nextOffset = offset;
        FFData.getInstance().clearList();
        fragment.mListAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        fragment.loadItems();
    }
    else
    {
        Crashlytics.log(Log.ERROR, "Log this error", "bad stuff happened!");
    }
}
```

The activity and fragment are fully running when the menu button is clicked. I also see that the code is run in the debugger. Running on genymotion(will try actual device), SDK 19, Nexus5

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure Crashlytics is initialized first by calling `Crashlytics.start(this);`
2. Crashlytics.log will message will be visible in your dashboard, associated with crash (Meaning if no crash/exception happens, log will not be sent...Crashlytics is a crash tracking service, if you need to track custom messages there are other tools for that).